# jQuery selector loads images from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, http-status-code-404

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax_data = 
        '<ul id="b-cmu-rgt-list-videos"><li><a href="{video.url}" '+
        'title="{video.title.strip}"><img src="{video.image}" '+
        'alt="{video.title.strip}" /><span>{video.title}</span></a></li></ul>';

    var my_img = $(ajax_data).find('img');
</script>`
```

ajax_data is data from a JS template engine where I need to get some part of it. The problem is that jQuery does a GET on the

`img src={video.image}: GET /test/%7Bvideo.image%7D HTTP/1.1`
(on Firefox Live HTTP headers).
This GET generates a 404 from the server.

Any clues on how to solve this?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Salut Guillaume. Welcome to SO. Please take a second to read the editing help: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help so that others do not need to reformat your questions.

Comment: Salut Spender, thanks I was looking for this :)

Comment: @spender `{video.image}` doesn't seem to get parsed by whatever template engine you are using. What engine *are* you using to replace those values?

Comment: You might want to better describe what you are trying to do so that people can propose alternate approaches. Your current approach is telling jQuery to build the markup in ajax_data, which I suspect is not what you want to do. You probably want your template engine to build the actual markup. Why are you trying to find the img tag?

Comment: actually this is a sample to show the problem. The "template engine" is mine, which is replacing values from an XML. I'm trying here to get a part of the full template, then I'll replace variables like {video.image} with the template engine.

Comment: Maybe an alternate approach is to get the img-tag with an regular expression?

Comment: As **edwin** say you need to use regex or at least you need to append your AJAX responce into the HTML page before get something from it! this is needed cause the ajax_data is not **DOM** but just **plain text**!!!

Comment: the img tag is a sample, in my case I need to get a big part of the template, maybe I should regexp the concerned part... I think I'm not using jQuery to do the right thing here.
I thought I could use jQuery to extract a part of some HTML using the jQuery selector, maybe I'm wrong :)

Comment: you can use jquery selector only on DOM, this means that ajax_data must be converted from plain text do DOM!!! for achieve this you need to put it  into your html body maybe by setting it to display:none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a [jquery object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) from html, it's immediately evaluated (because the document fragment is created), so this:

```
$("<img src='bob.jpg' />")
```

Immediately causes a fetch of the image.  The way I see it you had 3 quick options (and probably others, but hard to say without more context to your question):

1. Replace `{video.image}` before creating the jQuery object.
2. Remove `src="{video.image}"`, just find the `<img>` via the selector you already have and set the `src` attribute later, like this: `$(ajax_data).find('img').attr('src','myImage.jpg');`
3. Do everything you want via regex before inserting anything into the DOM.

Comment: I will investigate on points 2 and 3, maybe puting a class on the <img> tag and removing the src like you told.  Thanks a lot for your help :)